# Tried Everything but still this error occur - A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase

LoginPage.html

```
  <div layout="column" ng-app="HelpingHand" ng-controller="login" layout- 
  fill>
        <md-content>
   < div layout="column" >
   <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <input ng-model="email" type="email" placeholder="Email (required)" 
    ng-required="true">
    </md-input-container> 

     <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input ng-model="password" type="text">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-button ng-href="login.html" ng-click="emaillogin()" class="md- 
  raised md-warn">Login</md-button>
       <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Cancel</md-button>
  </div>
```

Login.js

```
  var app = angular.module('HelpingHand', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages']);
  app.controller('login', function($scope) {
  $scope.emaillogin = function(){
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, 
  $scope.password).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
   }
   });
```

Error Message Return the following Error - A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Error Code return the Following Error - auth/network-request-failed

what Mistake i do with this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.. Just mess with my project id

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was I was trying to navigate from the page prior to receiving a response back using `windows.location = "url"`.

This seems to be a timing issue with the response.  This offending issue is commented out below in the `if(true)` statement.

```
function toggleSignIn() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        // [START signout]
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        // [END signout]
    } else {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        if (email.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter an email address.');
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 4) {
            alert('Please enter a password.');
            return;
        }
        // Sign in with email and pass.
        // [START authwithemail]
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                alert('Wrong password.');
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
            document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        });
        // [END authwithemail]

        // clear user / pass 
        document.getElementById('email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('password').value = "";
        /*
        if (true) { 
        window.location = "{URL}";
        }
        */
    }
    document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: To fix and get back to what I wanted, I added the following:      var timer = setTimeout(function() {window.location='url'}, 3000);